# List Directories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to list all directories in this path `public_path().'/assets/fe/img/portfolio'`

[image]

```
dd(Storage::directories(public_path().'/assets/fe/img/portfolio'));
```

I kept getting `[]`, I suppose to get 5.

## Why ?

Comment: did you try to scan folder before this one like '/assets/fe/img/' ? to be sure it found every folder. if yes, maybe it's about folder right ?

Comment: @cyber8200 do you have this problem solved yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storage::directories() try to find directories in `storage/app/public` folder, certainly because you have asked it to do so in your filesystems.php file.

add this in `disks` array in filesystems.php file

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],
```

then you can use this syntax to get desired output

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk("public")->directories("assets/fe/img/portfolio")
```

assuming your `public` folder is in root directory and has following directory structure

[image]